# Different file sizes Android and Windows

Tags: android, windows, file

I have different file sizes for the same file (it is actually a folder, but I guess that doesn't make a difference) on Android and Windows:

Android:

```
File pic = new File("pathToFileOrFolder");
pic.length() // returns 4096
```

Windows file explorer says the following in the file properties:
3,26 MB (3.422.720,00 Bytes)

Can somebody tell me how to get the same value?

Comment: You need to recursively enumerate all files in this folder and subfolders, and add their file sizes. Right now you are querying the folder **object**, not it's contents.

Comment: Absolutely right! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make sure to account for hard/soft links. If you don't, you'll run the risk to wind up with endless recursion. Whether you want to include linked files or not is a question you'll have to answer yourself.